# Fetch Request "unrecognized selector" error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have two entities, one called projects and one called tasks, and projects can have many tasks to them. I have a fetch request that should fetch all the tasks associated with a project, but I am getting this error when tapping on a project to move to the view with the project's tasks on it:

```
Thread 1: Exception: "-[__NSConcreteUUID longLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002969b20"
```

Here are my two classes:

```
extension ProjectItem {
    @NSManaged public var projectId: UUID
    @NSManaged public var projectTitle: String
    @NSManaged public var task: NSSet
}

extension TaskItem {
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var isComplete: Bool
    @NSManaged public var title: String
    @NSManaged public var project: ProjectItem?
}
```

And here is my view and fetch request:

```
struct ProjectDetail: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @ObservedObject var projectItem: ProjectItem
    
    private var tasksInProject: FetchRequest<TaskItem>
    private var taskItems: FetchedResults<TaskItem> { tasksInProject.wrappedValue }
    
    init(_ project:ProjectItem) {
        self.projectItem = project


        self.tasksInProject = FetchRequest(
            entity: TaskItem.entity(),
            sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \TaskItem.createdDate, ascending: false)],
            predicate: NSPredicate(format: "project == %@", project.projectId as CVarArg))
    }

...

var body: some View {
    ForEach(taskItems, id:\.id) { taskItem in
        Text("\(taskItem.title)")
    }
}
```

Please help! I have been pulling my hair out over this for over a week now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TaskItem.project` is type of `ProjectItem?` not UUID, so try

```
self.tasksInProject = FetchRequest(
    entity: TaskItem.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \TaskItem.createdDate, ascending: false)],
    predicate: NSPredicate(format: "project.projectId == %@", project.projectId as CVarArg))
```